# scipy.integrate.odeint with segmentation fault

Tags: python, numpy

I am integrating a (somewhat large --- 687378 equation) system of ODEs using scipy.integrate.odeint.

It appears to be running fine, but then I get a sudden segmentation fault.  Not much of an error message: `Segmentation fault: 11`.

In inspecting what is happening, I have outputed the time at each evaluation of the functions.  The step size doesn't appear to be showing anything unusual, but then suddenly it drops from a step size of about 0.08 (which had been standard in the calculation) to no apparent change in the step size.  After about 20 evaluations where it outputs the same value of time, it simply stops and I get the segmentation fault error.

It appears that the integration was correct to this point.  I'm solving a system of equations that should approximate some simulations I've done, and it does seem to be a good fit. Unfortunately, I can't really create an MCVE since I've been asked to keep the data set this is based on private, and it seems to handle other examples okay.

I'm monitoring computer memory as it runs and there's no sign of anything unusual.

Any suggestions for what might be the cause and what I can do to test it?

Comment: It is probably a matter of "ressource exhaustion". So it would seem to me that 687378 equations represent too large a system to handle correctly. The following link is a collection of examples that generate "Segmentation faults". Some Python modules don't validate their arguments in a fail-safe way, some just run out of memory. I suspect that latter is the case with your large ODEs. Cf. https://wiki.python.org/moin/CrashingPython

Comment: @Ukimiku  Thanks for the comment.  This is not running out of memory.  The fact that it suddenly begins to use a step size of 0 suggests that the problem is something in the algorithm rather than simply running out of resources.